# Run an app within an app Android

Tags: android, smartphone

I am creating an app that i would like to have apps running within it like let's say an iframe on a website. Is this possible? For example i will open my app and it will show the Gallery of the phone but while running my app, and not just by opening the gallery app which will make my app minimized. I want it exactly like an iframe, is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

you can not run another app within your own application. You can do any of the following two

1. start the other app by sending intent message
2. or create the other app's features similarly in your own app.

According to your question if your need is to create a gallery then why aren't you creating a own gallery in your app? that will be more easier and flexible

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply. Well the thing is it's not just a gallery my idea, is be able when i open my app to choose which apps i want to have controlled, and instead of having to press home button to change app be able to "slide" through the apps i want to use, within my app.

Comment: oh sorry then, it is no possible exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can not run another app's Activities within your app in an iframe style for security reasons, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe that is is possible for Apps to run cross platform if there exist a common data framework that creates a uniform standard for how data is stored and referenced. So the data can exist in the cloud but referenced via each app independently of the mobile phone platform.